# How to pass CVV number in PayPal PayFlow Pro?

Tags: asp.net, paypal

The file VerisignPayment.cs provided by the PayPal API has a line of code

SaleTransaction trans = new SaleTransaction(user, connection, invoice, tender, PayflowUtility.RequestId);

How to pass CVV number to trans? 
I know that people (on my side) who have developed the payment gateway are using PayPal PayFlow Pro

Answer (score 0):

Hope this isn't too late -- I see you asked this question back in March -- but here's the info you need: The 'tender' is supposed to be a CardTender object, whose constructor takes a CreditCard object as its only value. The CreditCard object is what stores the CVV. So here's what it would look like:

```
CreditCard cc = new CreditCard('5105105105105100', '0113');
cc.Cvv2 = '111';
CardTender tender = new CardTender(cc);
SaleTransaction trans = new SaleTransaction(user, connection, invoice, tender, PayFlowUtility.RequestId);
```

Hope this helps! (Note: I'm not a C# programmer, so I hope I've got the syntax correct.)